# Подписанный скрипт перестал работать после истечения сертификата

Tags: windows, powershell, сертификат

Прошу помощи, чтобы разобраться в ситуации.
Есть скрипт на PowerShell. Скрипт подписан сертификатом. Сертификат не самоподписанный, на предприятии развёрнута полновесная система PKI, т.е. от скрипта собирается цепочка до Root CA[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Интересно случилось, когда у сертификата прошёл срок действия и запуск скрипта стал выдавать следующее сообщение:

```
C:\users\Public\Documents\Scripts\Security_monitoring.ps1 : Не удается загрузить файл C:\users\Public\Documents\Scripts
\Security_monitoring.ps1. Возможно, содержимое файла C:\users\Public\Documents\Scripts\Security_monitoring.ps1 изменено неавторизованным пользователем или процессом, так как хеш файла не совпадает с хешем, сохраненным в цифровой подписи.
Невозможно выполнить сценарий в указанной системе. Для получения дополнительных сведений выполните команду Get-Help about_Signing..
строка:1 знак:1
+ C:\users\Public\Documents\Scripts\Security_monitoring.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Ошибка безопасности: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Файл не изменялся, проверял через fc с резервной копией.
Провёл эксперимент - сделал простой скрипт, подписал, изменил код, не переподписывая - такая же ошибка.
Или я не туда смотрю.
Спасибо.

Comment: то есть, вопрос в том, почему для истекшего сертификата и изменённого файла выдает одну и ту же ошибку?

Comment: И в этом тоже. И в том, как бы системно эту проблему решить.

Comment: переподписать новым сертификатом.

Comment: это очевидный ответ, который становится неправильным, когда в подшефном хозяйстве скриптов больше, чем пять.

Comment: если сертификат истек, то как бы все очевидно - не пользоваться подписанными сертификатами.

Comment: если я всё правильно понимаю, то истёкшим сертификатом нельзя подписать новые файлы, но старые файлы не должны превращаться в тыкву, потому что на момент подписания сертификат был валиден

Comment: нет. если сертификат истек, то скрипт будет тыквой.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Необходимо при подписывании использовать временнУю метку
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $cert -IncludeChain "All" -TimestampServer "http://tsa.intranet.local/get.aspx" -FilePath Q:\1\hello_tmp2.ps1
Более подробно на [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0), например или [вот тут](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/using-digital-signatures-with-timestamp-server)